# Where is IIS on Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Tags: iis, windows-server, windows-server-2012

I just got Windows Server 2012 Essentials installed and I would like to set up my dev web projects in IIS on the server.  But I can't seem to find how to get to it?  When I remote to the machine with my admin account all I seem to have access to is the dashboard.

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: Turn windows features on/off on control panel -> programs and features?

Comment: you also have to install one of the IIS roles, you can do that in the server management

Comment: @D.Rosado how do I get to the control panel? All I seem to have access to is the dashboard.  I am logged in as an administrator.

Comment: The question is not about installing the feature, but navigating to it. They changed the navigation for no apparent reason. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentials comes with IIS preinstalled, so unless you uninstalled it for some reason, its there already.

I'm assuming you want to get to the IIS 8 admin tool.
In order to get there

- press the start button (on your keyboard)
- click on the Administrative Tools tile
- From there scroll down to IIS Manager and double click

OR

Hold down the windows key and press the R key (win+r)
then type in `inetmgr`

Comment: Exact same setup .... I'm having the same issue and following your instructions I can't see no listing for IIS and neither can search for it as 'inetmgr'.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried the universal search when you said "search for it". I don't think that will work, you need to have a keyboard with a windows key and press the windows key down and press the "r" key at the same time, then let go, to bring up the run dialog box. I'm sorry if my instructions sound weird, but without more details on what you have tried, this is as simple as I can make the instructions.

Comment: nw mate, I ended up reinstalling it altogther and then it appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently is not that simple on ws2012 as I thought, please try following this guide:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: those instructions do not work for server essentials considering there is no role manager in the dashboard for the essentials version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's whether he has it *installed* or not, it's that they changed how you GET to it. IIS manager USED to be accessible from Server Manager, but it is no longer so. In 2008 (and earlier, but I don't have a box readily available) from Server Manager, expand Roles, then Web Server. If you click "web Server" You see a "dashboard", displaying events, Services, Best Practices, Etc. WITHIN that, you can click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, and see the sites, and manage and configure the sites on the machine.

In 2012, you can ONLY see that dashboard information, events, service status, best practice, etc. There's *no way* to navigate into IIS and manage the sites and applications. Up in the top-right corner, the menu "Tools" (Between "Manage" and "View") contains IIS Manager.

I'd LOOOOOVE to see a transcript of the design session where this change was suggested. Mostly just to get the attendance, and then hunt them all down.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the IIS Management Console is enabled through via Control Panel -> Programs and Features.  From Server Manager, click Add roles and features and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `inetmgr.exe` at the below location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
```

Or you can run it from the run window

<kbd>Win + R</kbd> `-> inetmgr ->` <kbd>Enter</kbd>